# How to make Rest Api using codeigniter when getting output in html format

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

Hi  I have written code to retrieve books title from database table using codeigniter using this url

(localhost:81/sample_api/index.php/Book/get_books) when I type in browser i am getting output  like this.
output:

[image]

So I want to make REST API for this actually i have tried so many github projects but they did in complicated way and  I am unable to understand so please guid  me how to make REST API in codeigniter for this link .

```
public function get_books() {
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_books')->result();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            echo $row->title."<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can not view your localhost links.

Comment: @Mr.ED it's just  plain text not working link  actually i want to show the  method which i am following

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you get a simple HTML output, changing it to some other output format should be really simple

Comment: take a look at this project - https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: @NicoHaase  ok by json_encode this method it will convert into json but I am not getting output in Postman  so i want to get REST API concept will you please explain a simple way to do this.

Comment: I haven't told you to use JSON. But the same code that outputs HTML markup can be used to write just any output format

Comment: @NicoHaase so how this will be  work as API .

Comment: Just `echo` what you need to echo for the format you need. If JSON is not what you need, write what you need. Skip thinking about that API stuff, just define your output format and echo the data

Comment: @NicoHaase I am getting output after echo without any error , ok but i want to know how to make API so  i can use in other site that's what need . again I got few reference from github for api using codeigniter but some complex code are there which I unable to understand .

Comment: @NicoHaase just hint me what to do for same thing should work in postman i.e API

Comment: So which parts are you looking for? If you echo all needed data, what is missing for you to call this an "API"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make an API then you shouldn't be looping trough your result set but just output them as a json_encoded object or in some other way. The json example would look something like this:

```
public function get_books() {
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_books')->result();
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

Comment: Is your table called tbl_books or is that a constant which holds the table name ? If it is a constant than it should be like this: $this->db->get(tbl_books)->result();

Comment: @lgor llic yes that's table name